# Why is the UTS namespace isolation not working?

Tags: ubuntu, hostname, namespace

**1. Starting a shell process under a separate child UTS namespace**

```bsh
sudo unshare -f --mount-proc -u /bin/bash
```

**2. Change the hostname in this process**

```bsh
hostnamectl set-hostname newhostname
```

**3. Monitor the change from a different shell**

```bsh
$ hostname
newhostname
```

#### Expected Result

The process in the parent namespace to preserve its old hostname.

#### Result Got

Changing the hostname in the new UTS namespace also changed the hostname in the parent namespace.

---

Why is this happening? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, kernel version 5.10.23-xanmod1 (`uname -r`).

Comment: It works as expected on my Ubuntu 16 (except that I had to do it without `--mount_proc`, which failed due to EBUSY). Are the namespaces really different? Compare them with `ls -l /proc/YOURPID/ns/uts`.

Comment: I just tried in an Ubuntu 18.04 VM and got the inverse behavior. After running `sudo unshare -f -u /bin/bash` (like berndbausch, the `--mount-proc` gave an error, presumably since there is no mount location given and `/proc` is already mounted) and then `hostnamectl set-hostname newhostname`, running `hostname` in the unshared shell returned the old hostname while running `hostname` in a separate, new shell showed the new one.

Comment: @berndbausch yes I checked, the inodes are indeed different.

Comment: @terdon your experiment aligns with me. If I change the hostname from a non-unshared shell, the hostname change isn't reflected in the unshared shell, which is expected. But why doesn't the inverse work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hostnamectl` comes along the *systemd* environment and it doesn't execute the `sethostname(2)` system call. It asks *systemd* to do it, through the `/run/dbus/system_bus_socket` socket. As *systemd* didn't change namespace, it performs this in the initial namespace, changing the name of the old UTS namespace (the initial where it's running) to the new name provided and leaving the new UTS namespace with an unchanged name (contrary to OP's claim): the old hostname. There will be other side effects, like the file `/etc/hostname` being changed.

This can be checked using `strace`. There's no `sethostname(2)` inside, but there are visible systemd-related elements:

```
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/systemd/system/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=40, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
```

If one prevents the call above to succeed (by using `unshare -f -u -m /bin/bash` and then covering inside it all of `/run` with a `mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /run`), one gets:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

The dialog is later done through the socket opened like this:

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket"}, 30) = 0
```

In such environment one should use the low level "legacy" command `hostname` which is used for reading *or* changing the hostname. It does invoke directly the `sethostname(2)` system call: it will change the new UTS namespace's name and leave the old (initial) UTS namespace unchanged:

```
hostname newhostname
```

For `hostnamectl` to affect the new UTS namespace (like with a full container started with LXC), this requires more than an `unshare` command: a whole new instance of a *systemd* eco-system must be present in the new environment, probably requiring several other namespaces to be entered/unshared and a lot of additional boilerplate.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.